# Joomla Login redirection back to page to the previous page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have certain pages that require to a user to be logged in Joomla. When they click on the links to those pages a login box appears in an iframe overlay. Once they login, I want to redirect them back to the page they were trying to login to, however, Joomla seems to only allow a user to be redirected to a page that is predefined in the login form parameters. Is there a way to do this without completely hacking Joomla.

If not, does anyone have a recommendation on how to hack this an easy way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like

```
$return = JURI::getInstance()->toString();
$url    = 'index.php?option=com_user&view=login';
$url   .= '&return='.base64_encode($return);
$this->setRedirect($url, XiText::_('YOU_MUST_LOGIN_FIRST'));  // if you are in controller

or 

JFactory::getApplication()->redirect($url, XiText::_('YOU_MUST_LOGIN_FIRST'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `$this->setRedirect($link, $msg);`

For more information on this function refer here
http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JController/setRedirect

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]** I have solved this issue and implemented in the site. 
Follow [this link](http://socialmessage.in/index.php/articles/102-how-to-redirect-users-to-login-register-page-when-they-try-to-access-restricted-content-403-redirect-to-login-page-in-joomla), I have written a 5 step tutorial on how to do this.(No Code editing required).

> This is how you can do it.
>
> In Hidden Menu
>
> 1.Add New menu item : Call it eg. "Login Hidden Menu" . (Users won't see this menu).
>
> 2.Add a new menu item name it eg. "User Article upload "to Login hidden menu, Choose Menu Item type : "Create article".(or any other component which only registered users can access. But public can view, Give Access as "Registered" for this Menu.)
>
> In Main menu
>
> 1.Goto your Main Menu and create a menu item call it  "Submit Article to website".
>
> 2.Choose Menu Item type : Menu Item Alias and choose "User Article upload " (you created in Login hidden menu), give access as public.
>
> ALL DONE. Now when visitor clicks on "Submit Article to website" they will be redirected to login page instead of 403 error.