# Redirect JomSocial Successful Login to Original Page

Tags: redirect, authentication, joomla, joomla-extensions

I know that under JomSocial >> Config, there is a dropdown to redirect to specific pages. Does anyone know how to have the redirect go to the page that the user was on or the link in which they clicked?

IE. I click a copied link, it takes me to the login page, I login via Facebook (or via the Joomla Registration) and it takes me to one of the generic Jomsocial pages, rather than the original page.

Ideas?

Comment: Anyone? Still trying to find a resolution!

Comment: I'm not sure, but this may set you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475839/joomla-login-redirection-back-to-page-to-the-previous-page

Comment: Thanks! I'll forward to our devs. Maybe they will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

1. **JomSocialRedirect Plugin**

   The main purpose of this plugin is to prevent users of using (and abusing) the native Joomla's `com_users` registration.
   It can also control the login and logout redirection. You can also set the message that is displayed on each redirection.
2. **Override com_user registration** - Set this to yes to force your users to always use JomSocial registration, even if they try to
   decompose the links on your site and access to the site by using
   `http://www.site.name/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration`