# Joomla 2.5 redirect to requested page after login

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In joomla 2.5 user's are taken to predefined page after they have logged-in. 
But i need to redirect users to the previous page after they have logged-in, i have tried to search for it every where but i am unable find proper solution explaining what core file i need to modify ?

Comment: You don't edit core files, this is where plugins come in. They are there to manipulate the way Joomla works. Have a look at the Documentation for Plugin Development to get you started

Comment: my question is exactly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475839/joomla-login-redirection-back-to-page-to-the-previous-page

Comment: there must be a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an article with a little piece of javascript to browse the history of the user and call the page before the login form. Redirect the user on it on log in.

If you have a menue item (User/Login Form), there is, on the right hand side of the screen, a tab called Basic Options. The first field is called "Login Redirect". Put the article's URL there.

If you use the module: Again in the tab "Basic Options", you can redirect to Any menue item you want, so set a menue item (it has not to be actually showing up somewher) for the article